# Random variable with maximum variance and same expectation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, variance

Let $X$ be an integrable real random variable. For any $-\infty<a<b<\infty$, define $Y$ as $X$ on the event $X\not\in [a,b]$, and otherwise define it as $a$ with probability $\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{X\in[a,b]}b-X d\mathbb{P}$ and as $b$ with probability $\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{X\in[a,b]}X-a d\mathbb{P}$. It is easy to show that by construction $\mathbb{E}Y=\mathbb{E}X$. It is known that $Y$ maximises the variance among all random variables $Y'$ coinciding with $X$ off $[a,b]$ and having same expectation as $X$. How does one show this? I tried various partitions of $\Omega$ and investigated $\text{Var}Y-\text{Var}X$, but could not reach the conclusion sought, so there must be another way.

Anybody familiar with the topic? Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the scaffolding of this problem can be easily removed: write

$$E[X]=E[Y]=E[Y \mid X \in [a,b]] P[X \in [a,b]] + E[Y \mid X \not \in [a,b]] P[X \not \in [a,b]].$$

Some subtraction yields

$$E[Y \mid X \in [a,b]] P[X \in [a,b]] = E[X \mid X \in [a,b]] P[X \in [a,b]].$$

Now you can divide through to get

$$E[Y \mid X \in [a,b]] = E[X \mid X \in [a,b]].$$

Thus you can already assume WLOG that $X$ is supported on $[a,b]$ and then your hypothesis collapses to $E[Y]=E[X]$.

From there, yes, you can make the variance of $Y$ arbitrarily large if that's your only assumption.

Comment: Perhaps my comments made the main point of my post obscure. I edited it for more clarity. What I am not sure about is how to prove that any other random variable $Y'$ coinciding with $X$ off of $[a,b]$ (i.e. such that $Y'(\omega)=X(\omega)$ for all $\omega\in(Y'\not\in[a,b])$) and having same expectation as $X$, will have a smaller variance than $Y$.

Comment: @GGG It won't, that was the conclusion here. This only works if you demand that $Y$ is supported on $[a,b]$ (after making my WLOG assumption about $X$).

Comment: Can we construct an explicit counterexample then? I am sort of hesitant to dismiss the claim, since it was made by highly regarded mathematicians (https://www.jstor.org/stable/2044124 right after Lemma 2.2)

Comment: I have been able only to prove that $\text{Var}Y\geq \text{Var}X$ by exploiting conditional variance and Jensen's inequality, then a counterexample should be a $Y'$ such that $\text{Var}Y'>\text{Var}Y\geq \text{Var}X$, on top of the other requirements.

Comment: @GGG If this is really your only assumption then yes, you can make a counterexample. Dropping my WLOG assumption (even though it's harmless), say $X$ is U(0,2) distributed and your interval is $[0,1]$, then $Y$ is $X$ if $X \in [1,2]$ and otherwise can be *anything* with mean $1/2$, e.g. $1/2 \pm M$ with equal probability for an arbitrarily large $M$.

Comment: I think I see the misunderstanding now. I was understanding $Y'(\omega)=X(\omega)$ for all $\omega \in (X \not \in [a,b])$. I think you intended $Y'(\omega)=X(\omega)$ for all $\omega \in (X \not \in [a,b]) \cup (Y' \not \in [a,b])$. In other words, not only is $Y'=X$ whenever $X \not \in [a,b]$, but also if $X \in [a,b]$ then $Y' \in [a,b]$. This will break my proposed counterexample and is enough to make the result true.

Comment: But again, most of the scaffolding can be thrown out: the problem amounts to saying, given $x \in [a,b]$, construct a random variable supported on $[a,b]$ with mean $x$ and maximum variance.

Comment: In the paper referenced, the claim is that $Y'$ has to be equal to $X$ off of $[a,b]$, and have same expectation. This, as per my earlier clarification, means only $Y'(\omega)=X(\omega)$ for all $\omega\in (Y'\not\in[a,b])$. I think the union you wrote is a stronger assumption than the claim here, because $(Y'\not\in[a,b])\subseteq (X\not\in[a,b])$.

Comment: Am I understanding the English of the paper wrong here (I am no native speaker, btw)?

Comment: I can indeed prove the claim for $Y'$ coinciding with $X$ off of $[a,b]$ and valued in $[a,b]$ for $(X\in [a,b])$, it is pretty much the same as showing that $\text{Var}Y\geq \text{Var}X$. However this does not seem to be the claim in the paper to me, because the second condition we are adding is not mentioned (however, note that it does hold for $Y$, so we could presume it was intended implicitly).

Comment: I didn't read the original sentence in the paper.

Comment: I included the link in the third comment. The counterexample you provided does not apply to that formulation unfortunately, but I think it could be adjusted. If so, they might have stated it with a loose terminology. I'll check if it is so.